# Database design approach: suggestions needed

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I am designing training video marketplace application. There is going to be Paid and Unpaid customers. For Unpaid customers, I want to provide few videos as free access for selected training package.

For example, if there is total 10 training videos in a given training package, 4 videos are going to be free. But, to view remaining 6 videos, customer needs to purchase whole training package.

I am not able to decide proper approach to design database tables for this scenario.

Here is what I can think of. I am not sure this is going to be correct approach.

**First Approach:**
I am assuming, I need three tables like below:

- Customer Table (Columns: customer_id, customer info)
- Training Video Table (Columns: video_id, video url, free_access as boolean)
- Purchase Table (columns: Customer_id as foreign key, video_id as Foreign Key)

When user accessing any training video, I will check if the user is paid or unpaid. For this I will take help of Purchase_table. Then on the basis of boolean free_access column, video will be served/denied. But, this seems too costly performance wise (I might be wrong on this!).

**Second Approach:** 
I should create view on top of Training Video Table for Paid and Unpaid users to minimise access of videos for unpaid users. But, I am not sure how this is going to be implemented.

Should I go with approach one with some caching mechanism to avoid querying Purchase table for every video request. Do you think it is OK or can suggest any new approach.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The first approach sounds like a standard design; I see no issue with it as long as appropriate indexes are used. Any other approach this early could probably be considered premature optimization and/or convolution of a simple design for no discernible benefit. _...but I haven't used Django, so I don't know if that complicates things for you._

Comment: Ok. I will give more thought on the implementation. Honestly, I was not able to decide which approach to take. If possible, can you please add your comment as answer, so in case I don't get better approach, we can close this question with your suggestions.